# Text appears reversed when writing a visual with FlowDirection.RightToLeft to an XPS document

Tags: c#, wpf, right-to-left, xps, xpsdocument

I'm writing a WPF `FrameworkElement` to an XPS document using a custom `DocumentPaginator`, that breaks the element into `DocumentPage` instances. The code already works perfectly for English and other languages.

To support right-to-left languages, I'm setting the `FlowDirection` property of the element to `RightToLeft`. The on-screen result seems fine; controls are aligned to the right and text appears in order. However, when I'm writing the element to the XPS document, the text appears reversed (including English). Controls are still aligned correctly.

What is the correct way to write a `FrameworkElement` with `FlowDirection.RightToLeft` to an XPS document, so that RTL text appears correctly?

I'm using .NET 4 and VS 2010.